# Drag Pane to Expand or Shrink in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have three pane inside my HBox.

```
<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
   <children>
      <Pane id="First" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Pane id="Second" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Pane id="Third" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

I want to drag the border between First Pane & Second Pane. So that -

1. when I drag the border to the left First Pane become smaller and Second Pane become larger.
2. when I drag the border to the right First Pane become larger and Second Pane become smaller.

I hope the following image will explains my requirement.

[image]

Comment: use [SplitPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put first and second panes into SplitPane:

```xml
<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <SplitPane>
        <Pane id="First" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
        <Pane id="Second" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
    </SplitPane>
    <Pane id="Third" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"/>
</HBox>
```